# PWL constraint in cplex Python API v12.8

Tags: python, cplex

When I tried to use piecewise linear (PWL) function in Python, after I set the problem type to `cplex.Cplex.problem_type.LP`, the PWL cpnstraint (or function) disappear when I write out the model to the file. However if I specified the problem type is `cplex.Cplex.problem_type.MILP`, it said that no solution, although there exist solution in LP. So I want to ask if someone face this problem before and how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe is expected. PWL constraints are considered MILP modeling objects. When you change the problem type to an LP, the MILP modeling objects are removed. Given that the LP is feasible, it sounds like your PWL constraint has introduced a conflict or there is something wrong with the definition of the PWL.

What exactly is the solution status code that you are getting when solving the MILP? That is, what is the value of `Cplex.solution.get_status()`? What does the engine log contain? These will likely give you some useful information.

In case you haven't found it, the CPLEX User's Manual contains a section on piecewise linear constraints [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/pwl/01_pwl_title_synopsis.html). See also the `transport.py` example that is included when you install CPLEX.

Comment: Thank you. I found the file `transport.py` on github, but then they used SOS in it, so I skipped it. The file in cplex package that I downloaded is different, I didn't know that